# Using tags option in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I'm trying to run multiple tests in cucumber framework using tags option from `TestRunner.java` file. I've tried something like below, but it didn't help as expected.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Feature"
        ,glue={"stepDefinition"}
        ,format = {"html:Results"}
        ,tags = {"@test1","@test2","@test3"}
        )
```

From several posts, I could see that we should use **--tags @ --tags @....** for multiple tags with **AND** functionality. But I believe that the format would work only if I trigger the execution from command prompt, but not in class file. So please help me in updating this part.

Comment: This should work if you have tests which have all 3 tags. Can you elaborate 'it didn't help as expected' ? Error / stack trace ?

Answer (score 1):

Your runner class is looking for a feature file which has all the three tags `"@test1","@test2","@test3"`. If you have `@test1, @test2, @test3` in 3 different feature files but not in a single feature file then try as below.

```
tags = {"@test1,@test2,@test3"}
```

DO NOT give quotes for each tag. Just a quote before and after all the tags separated by comma.